# I am getting a 302 error in my Cs50 Finance project

Tags: http, syntax-error

I am currently doing the Finance CS50 project and after changing my code several times, it finally allows me to register but now it wont log in because of a HTTP 302 error. How do I go about solving this?

I changed my code a couple of times and as well as adjusted the SQL table.